# Link list warning Dereferencing null pointer Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a link list node and I get this warning not sure what's causing it.

The line `temp->data = 100` throws an error saying "**Dereferencing NULL pointer 'temp'**".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node Node;
typedef struct node* link;

#define MIN  0

struct node
{
    int data;
    link pNext;
};

static Node* pHead, *pTail;

int main()
{
    Node* pn;
    link temp = (link)malloc(sizeof(node));
    int max;
    int A[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    temp->data = 100;
    
}
```

**Error in Visual studio 2019**

[image: Error in Visual studio 2019]

Comment: This isn't valid C, since `node` in `sizeof(node)` is not defined anywhere. In `c` you need `sizeof(struct node)` or `sizeof(Node)` (because `Node` _is_ defined).

Comment: Or even better: `link temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);`

Comment: I don't know about the warning you get from VC (I don't use that tool myself), but it looks like a static checker -- perhaps it's warning that `malloc` can return NULL and you don't check for that case. Adding error checking will help in that case. eg: `if (!temp) exit(2);` before you use temp.

Comment: It's almost exactly as described in the help page for C6011: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6011?view=msvc-160 .

Comment: You shouldn't hide pointers behind a typedef, it will only result in bugs. Use this instead to achieve what you want: `typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* pNext;
} Node;`

Comment: `sizeof(node)` What is `node`? You do not show a type or variable with that name. In C the type is `struct node`. Only in C++ a type `node` would be available as well. The code in the picture is longer and it is not clear for me where the error is reported. Are you sure it is in the part you copied here?

Comment: @ Paul Hankin that was issue thanks for the insight.
@ Lundin I see your point will do that in the future.